# Return class without changing anything

Tags: python

I want to make the next function return a new state that is updated with the changed / new variable. The test_next_state is a test, hence fixed.

```
def test_next_state_immutable():

    s1 = State(v1 = False, v2 = True, v3 = "open")
    s2 = State(v1 = True, v2 = True, v3 = "open")

    res = s1.next(v1 = True)
    assert s1 != s2
```

This is my solution to it, but my problem is that when creating tempState it points to the object self and changes the orginal value which I don't want to. I want to return a new State, without changing anything in the old state.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, Optional
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True, init=False)
class State:
    state: dict[str, Any]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        object.__setattr__(self, "state", kwargs)

    def next(self, **kwargs) -> State:
        tempState = dataclasses.replace(self)
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            tempState.state[k] = v
        return tempState

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(tuple(sorted(self.state)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new instance of `State`, using a `dict` created from the current state and any updates using the `|` operator.

```
@dataclass(frozen=True, order=True, init=False)
class State:
    state: dict[str, Any]

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.state = dict(kwargs)

    def next(self, **kwargs):
        return State(**(self.state | kwargs))
```

Prior to Python 3.9, you'll need to use `collections.ChainMap` instead of the `|` operator.

```
import collections

...

    def next(self, **kwargs):
        return State(**collections.ChainMap(kwargs, self.state))
```

Comment: The `ChainMap` solution needs to swap the order so `kwargs` comes before `self.state`; `ChainMap` gives value priority to the *first* mapping passed, not the last, so passing `self.state` first means existing values are used instead of the new ones from `kwargs`.

Comment: I even looked at the documentation (poorly, it would seem) to check which order was needed :(

Comment: Rather than chainmap, you could just use `{**self.state, **kwargs}` although I would use a variable before splatting that into the constructor

Comment: I mentioned `ChainMap` mostly because I always forget it exists. Theoretically, it's more efficient, since it doesn't have to construct a new `dict`; it just stores the existing dicts to iterate over later, which in this case is immediately. (A benefit it has over `|` as well.)

Answer (score 1):

`dataclasses.replace` with no arguments is equivalent to shallow copying the instance, which means both instance share an alias to the same `dict` as their `.state` attribute. You're not even using `replace` to change anything, so the minimal fix is to add an `import copy` to the top of the file and change:

```
tempState = dataclasses.replace(self)
```

to

```
tempState = copy.deepcopy(self)
```

which will break the aliasing between `tempState.state` and `self.state` by *recursively* copying to get a deep copy.

Alternatively, in this case where making the new `dict` is pretty easy, you can just make the new `dict` up front and and use it with `replace`, e.g.:

```
def next(self, **kwargs) -> State:
    return dataclasses.replace(self, state=self.state | kwargs) # dict union added in 3.9

# 3.7-3.8 version without dict union operator:
def next(self, **kwargs) -> State:
    temp_state = self.state.copy()
    temp_state.update(kwargs)
    return dataclasses.replace(self, state=temp_state)
```

This assumes the possibility that there are other fields besides `state` so `replace` is useful to preserve them; if not, chepner's solution of directly constructing a new `State` rather than using `replace` to base it on `self` is a more straightforward solution.